# How to create a loop for a function that uses two arguments to identify proxy SNPs in R?

Tags: r, genetic

I am trying to identify proxy SNPs for a list of SNPs using the "proxysnps" R package. I'm using the get_proxies function which requires the chromosome and position as seperate arguments.

e.g. get_proxies(chrom = NA, pos = NA, pop = NA)

I have a dataframe of about 300 obs of  2 variables in the following format:
e.g.

```
chr    pos
2       16699432
2       213728160
4       93764747
```

I would like to loop through my dataframe get proxies for each of my SNPs.

I'm quite new to R and I did try but I can use some help!

Thanks,

Comment: Eventually `mapply(FUN=get_proxies, chrom=df$chr, pos=df$pos)` or `mapply(FUN=get_proxies, df$chr, df$pos)`

Comment: Thank you so much jogo, I gave this a go and got something like this:          [,1]           [,2]          [,3]         
CHROM     Integer,1102   Integer,987   Integer,960  
POS       Integer,1102   Integer,987   Integer,960                                        I was expecting the proxy snps loci, can I use apply? I'll have a little play with it, but thank you so much for the head start I really appreciate it